# is it possible to access an elements function from another element? polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Lets say i have an `element A`

```
//imports
<dom-module id="element-A">
    <style></style>
<template>
    <content>
      //some content
    </content>
</template>

<script>
    // element registration
    Polymer({
        is: "element-A",
        aCustomFunction: function(e){
          //just some code
        }
    });
</script>
```

What if i want to access the function `aCustomFunction` from another different element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in regular way for example

if I have this element

```
<element-A id="someid"></element-A>
```

so I can go and do

```
 var element = document.getElementById("someid");
 element.aCustomFunction('someE');
```

or

```
 this.$.someid.aCustomFunction('someE');
```

In some cases the getElementById dont work You can use the appropriate polymer api to find this element. 
The idea that you dont have to do something special but find the element and  use it like an object.

Comment: That explains a lot, let me push my luck and extend the question here on the comments... what if you only have the functions name and the element (whose function you want to access) is anonymous?

Comment: I dont understand can you give an example?

Comment: element B wants to access  element A's function, but it only knows the name of the function. Nothing more. It doesn't even care if element A exists. Its like accessing the function from a global scope. (only that this time, its defined within element A)

Comment: I dont know if it possible, You have to know the name of the element to active the function.
If you want to have the same function in more objects, something like inheritance between elements you cansee Dmitry's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the function from one element in another, then you must use [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html).
This is simply way to extend you components according to the rules of the Polymer.

Comment: Sounds like you mixed something up. I can't see how behaviors are related to calling methods from other components.

Comment: The approach of using behaviors allows to use the same function in different components.  If the task is simply to take the function of a single component, and not to change it, it's method is the easiest.

Comment: Yup, that's right, but I think that's a different thing than what the question is about. Behaviors allow to reuse the same method(s) for different components so you don't have to implement them in each component individually, but if you want to call such a method from outside the component you need to go the way @Alon explained.

Comment: I agree, it all depends on the purpose.